# VSTS Hosted Agent 2017 : Run Powershell Script for Dll versioning in Build definition

Tags: powershell, msbuild, azure-devops, powershell-2.0, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

I want version my DLL with every build and release for that i have used powershell script as :

```
 foreach ($file in $files) {
    $filecontent = Get-Content($file)
    echo "updating version for $file"
    attrib $file -r
    $filecontent | %{$_ -replace 'AssemblyVersion\("[0-9]+?(\.([0-9]+?|\*)){1,3}"\)', $('AssemblyVersion("' + $NewVersion + '")') } |    
                  %{$_ -replace 'AssemblyFileVersion\("[0-9]+?(\.([0-9]+?|\*)){1,3}"\)', $('AssemblyFileVersion("' + $NewVersion + '")') } | 
                  %{$_ -replace '<AssemblyVersion>[0-9]+?(\.([0-9]+?|\*)){1,3}<', $('<AssemblyVersion>' + $NewVersion + '<') } | 
                  %{$_ -replace '<FileVersion>[0-9]+?(\.([0-9]+?|\*)){1,3}<', $('<FileVersion>' + $NewVersion + '<') } |
                  %{$_ -replace '<Version>[0-9]+?(\.([0-9]+?|\*)){1,3}<', $('<Version>' + $NewVersion + '<') } | Out-File -Encoding "UTF8" $file
```

> But earlier i was using azure/on premise build server on which
>   versioning was working properly.
>
> No i switched to hosted agent, Powershell script task runs successfult
>   but version of dll remains as 1.0.0.

Any solution to get this work on Hotsed agent as well ?

Comment: the files paths are correct?

Comment: yes file path are correct

Comment: you need to start debugging the script by add `Write-Host $variable` in each line and check exactly what the script does.

Comment: but it works when i select azure vm agent or on premises agent

Comment: but it doesn't work in Hosted agent, so don't you ant to check why?

Comment: yes but i wnt be able to login to hosted agent

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand.

Comment: what i meant to say is, i cant login to hosted agent where artifacts are built, rather i need download it on local.

Comment: what the problem to debug the script? maybe in hosted agent  the behavior is different because another values.

Comment: ok,,,,just wanted to make sure it should be admin privilege issue

Comment: Can you use a market task for this?  See [this](https://github.com/colindembovsky/cols-agent-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/VersionAssemblies)